# Why does the formula for latus rectum of ellipse simplify as shown?

Tags: conic-sections, radicals

Half the length of the latus rectum of the ellipse can be found with:

y = ± (b/a) √(b^2 )

which the text book simplifies to

y = ± b^2/a

why is it not ?

y = ± b|b|/a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it is but both possible are "included" via the  $\pm$. Though even stronger is that your $b>0$ so that $|b|=b$.